# 'onpageshow' not triggering on Android WebView app

Tags: android, html, cordova, caching, webview

So I'm currently trying to figure out a way to fully reload a page of an Android Cordova webview app when that page is navigated to via the Android back button.

Currently, when the back button is clicked, the app will open a cached version of the page with all user input still in the input fields. We need the fields to be empty when the user hits the back button.

I've done a lot of searching today and the most promising/relevant suggestion I've come across is to use 'onpageshow' and check to see if the page transition is persisted or not and then either reload the page or not.

The problem I'm having is that 'onpageshow' seems to behave in the exact same manner as 'onpageload' and will not trigger when a page loads via the back button.

Unfortunately I can't post any code as this is for my work so if you can't help me then that's fine but I'm just hoping someone has a suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried with `pagebeforeshow`. Otherwise you can reset your form on back event.

Comment: pagebeforeshow also does not appear to trigger when a user navigates to the page via the back button. It seems as though no javascript will. Perhaps there is someway to clear the cache during the transition?

Answer (score 0):

For problems like that I normally implement my custom history stack and map the back button to it.

document.addEventListener('backbutton', backHistory, false);

**EDIT:**

I want to say, is that I implement my own history mechanism, every link in the app that is clicked is added to a history array, like this:

```
history.push(url);
```

So, when I want to go back:

```
backHistory = function() {
   var url = history.pop();
   //Js function to navigate
}
```

Comment: This still accesses the cached copy of the page so I am unable to reload everything as no javascript will execute.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/README.md) then you can execute javascript after finishing pageload by executing `executeScript` in `loadstop` callback function.

It is also possible to clear the cache by `clearcache`